# Generic way to convert Element to Widget

Tags: java, gwt

I created a component which root element is a `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element`

```
Element select=DOM.createSelect();
...
```

Now, I would like this `Element` to be a `Widget`. How do I do that?

Until now, the only way I found is:

```
Element select=DOM.createSelect();
...
FlowPanel div=new FlowPanel(); //This will become a <div> tag.
div.getElement().appendChild(select.getElement());
return div;
```

but this causes my `<select>` to be wrapped in a `<div>`. Is there a way to make the `Element` be a widget without having it wrapped into a `<div>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about extending `Widget` and providing the element to `setElement`? This is how widgets are built (have a look at the code of `ListBox` for an example that uses a `<select>`)